# a2ensite doesn't show all sites in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I just did a big reinstall of Apache2 (Debian 2.4.4-6, libapache2-mod-php5 5.5.0~rc3+dfsg) and when it reset, all of my vhosts broke. Wondering if I accidentally purged my vhost configurations, I went to check:

```
d8uv@ddd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  798 Jun  2 08:27 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  394 Jul  9  2012 domain1.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  422 Jul 26  2012 domain2.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  427 Apr 28  2010 domain3.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  400 Apr 28  2010 domain4.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  393 Oct 26  2010 domain5.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6432 Jun  2 08:27 default-ssl.conf
```

All there, so let's see if I can enable them:

```
d8uv@ddd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo a2ensite 
Your choices are: 000-default default-ssl
Which site(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
```

So, the configuration files exist, but they're not being seen by a2ensite. Perhaps vhosting is turned off in the main config file?

```
d8uv@ddd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ tail /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look very closely at the include statements. Do you see it yet? No?

it includes `sites-enabled/*.conf`, so rename your configfiles so they have the .conf extension.

Comment: Either that or update your Include statement to include everything.

Comment: That's exactly it--thank you very much!

Comment: @Zoredache that won't make them show up in a2ensite, which also only looks at *.conf

Comment: wow you saved my life. for some reason I didn't pay attention to the fact that default ones now have .conf extention